# Add image column with AddColumns in Power Apps

Tags: image, powerapps

I am trying to populate a browse gallery with data form Table1 grouped by PRODUCTO, and I want to add as well an image colunm from the original table, but Power Apps cannot recognize this new column as image data. I tried to use [image] after the name of the new column as it is required in excel files, but unsuccesfully.

This is the code I am using:

```
SortByColumns(Search(Filter(AddColumns(GroupBy(Table1;"PRODUCTO";"NuevaTabla");"TStock";Sum(NuevaTabla.STOCK;STOCK);"TMin";Sum(NuevaTabla.MINIMO;MINIMO);"IMAGEN";NuevaTabla.IMAGEN);TMin -TStock >0);TextSearchBox1.Text; "PRODUCTO");"PRODUCTO";If(SortDescending1; SortOrder.Descending; SortOrder.Ascending))
```

Comment: Is the IMAGEN column a url that links to an image, or does it contain the image bytes  itself?

Answer (score 0):

Image files are stored in OneDrive and the link is in an excel table with the following format:

.\images\abrillantador.jpg

It works fine in the application but when the column is created with the command AddColumns that it is recognized as text instead of a url link.